# Test events raised by Fault<T> messages in saga state machine

Tags: unit-testing, masstransit

I'm trying to unit test my MassTransit saga state machine

```
During(
                Processing,
                When(CreateAgreementFaulted)
                    .Then(
                        behaviorContext => behaviorContext.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsFailed += 1)
                    .If(
                        context => context.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsCreated + context.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsFailed == context.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsToCreate,
                        (s) => s.TransitionTo(Done)),
                When(AgreementCreated)
                    .Then(
                        behaviorContext => behaviorContext.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsCreated += 1)
                    .If(
                        context => context.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsCreated + context.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsFailed == context.Saga.NumberOfDocumentsToCreate,
                        (s) => s.TransitionTo(Done)));
```

```
public Event<Fault<CreateAgreementMessage>> CreateAgreementFaulted { get; private set; }
public Event<CreatedAgreementMessage> AgreementCreated { get; private set; } = null!;
```

I can test the functionality when the test harness publishes `await TestHarness.Bus.Publish(new CreatedAgreementMessage);` but I would also like to test when a consumer throws an error when trying to consume the `CreateAgreementMessage`.

Maybe I'm misusing the system and should let the consumer publish a `CreateAgreementFailMessage` instead of letting it throw an exception.

Here is how I test AgreementCreated event:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task When_in_state_Processing_all_successful_documents_processed_Then_transition_to_Done()
        {
            var createdAgreementMessage = Fixture.Create<CreatedAgreementMessage>();

            await SaveSagaInstance(new CreateAgreementsState()
            {
                CorrelationId = createdAgreementMessage.RequestCorrelationId,
                NumberOfDocumentsFailed = 0,
                NumberOfDocumentsCreated = 0,
                NumberOfDocumentsToCreate = 1,
                CurrentState = nameof(CreateAgreementsStateMachine.Processing),
            });

            await TestHarness.Bus.Publish(createdAgreementMessage);
            
            var isConsumed = await GetSagaStateMachineHarness().Consumed.Any<CreatedAgreementMessage>();
            var isInDone = await GetSagaStateMachineHarness().Sagas.Any(s => s.CurrentState == nameof(CreateAgreementsStateMachine.Done));

            isConsumed.Should().BeTrue();
            isInDone.Should().BeTrue();
        }
```

I've tried publishing a `Fault<CreateAgreementMessage>`, but that does not seems to work and I think I know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually publish Fault messages. Try something like this:

```
await harness.Bus.Publish<Fault<CreateAgreementMessage>>(new
{
     Message = new { CorrelationId = createdAgreementMessage.RequestCorrelationId }
});
```

If you want to verify that the state moved to your expected state you can also add this:

```
var sagaState = provider.GetRequiredService<IndexedSagaDictionary<YOUR_STATE>>();
sagaState.Add(new SagaInstance<ReAllocationState>(new ReAllocationState
{
     CorrelationId = createdAgreementMessage.RequestCorrelationId,
     CurrentState = nameof(CreateAgreementsStateMachine.Processing)
}));

var sagaHarness = GetSagaStateMachineHarness();

(await sagaHarness.Consumed.Any<Fault<CreateAgreementMessage>>()).Should().BeTrue();

(await sagaHarness.Exists(createdAgreementMessage.RequestCorrelationId, sagaHarness.StateMachine.Faulted)) // Your expected state
        .Should().NotBeNull()
        .And
        .Be(correlationId);
```